# Remove a Member from a PowerShell Object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to remove a member (specifically, a NoteProperty) from an object. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`Select-Object` with `ExcludeProperty` is good for removing a property from a collection of objects.

For removing a property from a single object this method might be more effective:

```
# new object with properties Test and Foo
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ Test = 1; Foo = 2 }

# remove a property from PSObject.Properties
$obj.PSObject.Properties.Remove('Foo')
```

Comment: Ah! I was tooling around with the `Remove` method and couldn't get it to work, but it makes sense that you'd have to apply it specifically to the class with the properties in it. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I was messing around with Remove last night and from what I can tell it doesn't always work. Try `Get-Process -id $pid | % { $_.psobject.properties.remove('__NounName'); $_} | % __NounName`.  It is not surprising it would work with a psobject or pscustomobject even.  OTOH I was able to get it with DisplayHint on Get-Date.

Comment: That's a good point @KeithHill. I too discovered later some objects are immutable, or at least cannot be altered this way. You can witness the same symptoms if you try to manually change one of their properties, e.g. `$_.__NounName = "some new value"`

Comment: @Tohuw: I think what it comes down to is that you can only remove `NoteProperty` members this way. While they are typically found on custom PS objects, PS also occasionally adds `NoteProperty` properties to .NET types (whose properties are of type `Property`), such as `DisplayHint` on `[System.DateTime]`, which explains Keith's experience.

Comment: What about Remove-ItemProperty https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849770.aspx?

Comment: @felixfbecker I couldn't find a good way to send objects to `Remove-ItemProperty`. Piping `Get-Service` to it resulted in `Cannot find path 'C:\System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController'`.

Comment: The down-side with using select is it forces you to input *every single property you want* instead of excluding one property. This can be a huge burden on objects with lots of properties

Comment: Can you do `.Properties.Add`? I tried but got only errors about argument count no matter how many arguments I'm using.

Comment: I could Add a NoteProperty, e.g. `$obj = New-Object psobject;
$np = New-Object psnoteproperty MyProperty, MyValue;
$obj.PSObject.Properties.Add($np);
$obj;
`

Answer (score 36):

I don't think you can remove from an existing object but you can create a filtered one.

```
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PsObject -Property @{ Test = 1}
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Foo -Value Bar
$new_obj = $obj | Select-Object -Property Test
```

Or

```
$obj | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty Foo
```

This will effectively achieve the same result.

Comment: The part `-Property *` is really necessary or it doesn't work. Thanks for the tip Andy!

Answer (score 12):

I found the following helps if you're interested in removing just one or two properties from a large object.  Convert your object into JSON then back to an object - all the properties are converted to type NoteProperty, at which point you can remove what you like.

```
   $mycomplexobject = $mycomplexobject | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json

    $mycomplexobject.PSObject.Properties.Remove('myprop')
```

The conversion to JSON and back creates a PSCustomObject. You'll have the original object expressed and then you can remove as desired.

Comment: While I see what you're going for there, that involves lots of mutation I don't want to perform on an object when the above methods work fine and don't require that.

Answer (score 2):

If can depend on the type of object or collection you want to remove from. Commonly its a Collection (array) of objects like you might get from 'import-csv' which you can do it pretty easily.

```
$MyDataCollection = Import-CSV c:\datafiles\ADComputersData.csv
$MyDataCollection
Windows Server : lax2012sql01
IP             : 10.101.77.69
Site           : LAX
OS             : 2012 R2
Notes           : V

Windows Server : sfo2016iis01
IP             : 10.102.203.99
Site           : SFO
OS             : 2012 R2
Notes           : X
```

The to remove a property from each of these:

```
$MyDataCollection | ForEach { $_.PSObject.Properties.Remove('Notes') }

Windows Server : lax2012sql01
IP             : 10.101.77.69
Site           : LAX
OS             : 2012 R2

Windows Server : sfo2016iis01
IP             : 10.102.203.99
Site           : SFO
OS             : 2012 R2
```

Comment: No need for the loop: `$MyDataCollection.PSObject.Properties.Remove('Notes')` also does the trick.