# Removing metadata from multiple .mp4s in subdirectories using Powershell

Tags: powershell, metadata, mp4

Goal: Remove title and comments for all .mp4 files in 'e:\movies2' directory and sub-directories. I found a helpful script but have hit a point where I can Select the data I want to remove, but not actually remove.

```
Function Get-FileMetaData
{
  Param([string[]]$folder)
 foreach($sFolder in $folder)
  {
   $a = 0
   $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
   $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder)

   foreach ($File in $objFolder.items())
    { 
     $FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT
      for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++)
       { 
         if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a))
           {
             $hash += @{$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a))  =
                   $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) }
            $FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash
            $hash.clear() 
           } 
       } 
     $a=0
     $FileMetaData
    } 
  } 
} 

$movieMetadata = Get-FileMetaData -folder (gci e:\movies2 -Recurse -Directory).FullName
$movieMetadata | Select Title, Comments
```

The following does not work:

```
$movieMetadata | Clear-Variable Title, Comments
```

Can I fix this, or is there a way to set Title and Comments to $null?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905060/remove-a-member-from-a-powershell-object may help you

Comment: The `$FileMetaData` variable is NOT the _File Meta Data_ object. It's a custom object/sealed dictionary you've made which contains the same fields. This will not affect the actual files on your system. Now if your question was regarding how to remove the Properties title and comments from each 'PSObject' you need to use `$movieMetadata | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty Title,Comments`

Comment: If what you want is to strip certain metadata from the .mp4 files, I think this maybe accomplished using fmpeg. I tried searching for documentation on this, but that seems to be very hard to find. You could try a command like this: `ffmpeg -i testfile.mp4 -metadata title= -c copy testfilestripped.mp4`. Not sure if you can also get rid of comments at the same time by adding `comment=`

Comment: @AP. Thanks, I understand and agree that my current method will not work for me. How can I accomplish changing the extended properties of the actual files on the system without creating new objects?